# How to detect a Paste operation in a textbox?

Tags: vb6, textbox, detect, paste

I want to detect when the user pasted something into the textbox.  I want to detect it whether the user used the mouse or keyboard.

This is vb6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Karl E. Peterson's [HookXP](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/HookXP/) is a pretty cool code sample that shows you how to capture a paste event, along with a bunch of other interesting stuff.  I modified and stripped it down a bit, and was able to do what you asked, so I can vouch that it works.  I'd post it here, but I'd be violating his [license](http://vb.mvps.org/license.asp).

Comment: +1 For HookXP, +1 again for not pasting the code here! Karl **hates** that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is to subclass the textbox and detect the WM_PASTE event.